# Use old purchase theme for website development or not?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a purchased theme from ThemeForest. The theme name is Mobel. That theme's last update was in Jan 2018. So I am not sure to use that same theme for my latest development of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use latest version because many themes was not working proper and latest theme provide new functionality so i suggest to you use updated version.